# SQL Server Express to SQL Server Standard upgrade?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

The database size on our SQL Server Express database is around 10GB. I checked our database size and it said 38GB.

1. Do I need to upgrade to SQL Server Standard edition?
2. Is it expensive to upgrade?
3. Would the web hosting company be able to provide us with the license?

Our website has been very slow and unreliable lately

Comment: When asking vendor specific questions, please tag properly.

Comment: i tried sql and sql express but I was only allowed 1 tag.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210) and POB

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to upgrade to SQL Standard Edition?
>   Our website has been very slow and unreliable lately

Depends.

If your sites are still working then that implies that SQL server hasn't stopped accepting new data. I would expect exceptions along the lines of `"Could not allocate space because the '<FG_NAME>' filegroup is full"` if you were hitting the 10Gb limit already.

The 10Gb is *per database* not per server, so if your 38Gb is from several databases you may not have hit the limit yet. Also it doesn't count transaction log files so you might have massive log files (because your backup and other maintenance plans are not suitable for your recovery model for instance) that are responsible the majority of the space consumed.

> Is it expensive to upgrade?

This is not the right place for licensing/pricing information - such information changes regularly so any answer would quickly become obsolete and therefore incorrect. For current absolute prices consult your preferred software dealer(s) or the manufacturer directly. For a view on what is expensive and what isn't consult your accountant!

> Would the web hosting company be able to provide us with the license?

Depends. You'll have to ask them that. Some will, some won't. We don't even know what sort of hosting arrangement you have so we wouldn't be able to help even if we were the right people to ask.

Comment: hi, thanks very much for the reply !! I got 38GB for a single database (the live site one) but no house keeping was done of late and we got rid of 5GB... it allowed our site to work again. The site stopped taking orders and we couldn't update with new pictures on products... I think we will have to go with an upgrade at some stage.

Answer (score 0):

Licence costs are available from MicroSoft's site. I don't know if you can still get new licences, SQL 2008 R2 has entered it's last leg of support.

The web hosting company can advise whether they will provide the licence, and what their fees will be, or what licence they offer as alternative. Shop around, this is expensive.

Check what version of SQL you are running on, if your database is functioning at 3x the maximum tolerance, I doubt you are actually running on SQL Express.

Run this:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') Edition, 
CASE SERVERPROPERTY('ENGINEEDITION') 
WHEN 1 THEN 'Personal or Desktop Engine (Not available in SQL Server 2005 and later versions.)'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Standard (This is returned for Standard, Web, and Business Intelligence.)'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Enterprise (This is returned for Evaluation, Developer, and both Enterprise editions.)'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Express (This is returned for Express, Express with Tools and Express with Advanced Services)'
WHEN 5 THEN 'SQL Database'
END EngineEdition
, SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') ProductVersion
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx

Comment: hi, our hosting company said we should be able to get one from a Microsoft Partner and you have the access to apply and upgrade the licence yourself - they won't do it for us. It says we are running Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (X64)   Jun 28 2012 08:36:30   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor) . ***EDIT I ran your Query: Express Edition with Advanced Services (64-bit) Express (This is returned for Express, Express with Tools and Express with Advanced Services)10.50.4000.0